# Eloquent not updating first item in collection

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I don't understand why this function won't update the first app and change its lock state to 0 and rest to 1. It should update all apps with pending status.

```
   public function updateLockState( $stu_id )
   {

    $apps = Application::where('stu_id', $stu_id)->get();

    $acceptedApps = $apps->whereIn('status', [ 'ACCEPTED_W_SCHOLARSHIP', 'ACCEPTED_WO_SCHOLARSHIP', 'ACCEPTED_BYSTUDENT', 'ACCEPTED_CONDITIONALLY', 'UNDER_REVIEW', 'REGISTERED' ]);

    if ( $acceptedApps->count() == 0 )
    {
       // This has two apps showing in descending order by rank.
        $pending_apps = $apps->where('status', 'PENDING')->sortByDesc('rank');

        foreach ($pending_apps as $key => $value)
        {

            if ( $key == 0 )
            {
                $value->update(['locked' => 0]);
            }
            else
            {
                $value->update(['locked' => 1]);
            }

        }

    }

    dd();

}
```

I have even tried to use DB:table() function for updating apps with id in where clause but it gives same result. This function is executed on the first line of the index function i.e its the first function to run on the page that interacts with apps. It ends with a dd() or exit() which stops anything else to run.

EDIT:

When I manually update rank values in db, I run this script and it should update locks but it is not. It should make lock = 0 for first app and lock = 1 for all other app and since apps are ordered by ranks desc it, app with 18 rank should be on top hence its lock = 0 after update:

[image]

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: I am not getting errors. Its just not updating the locks when I update the rank values manually in the db.

Answer (score 0):

sortByDesc() sorts in descending order BUT it keeps the keys in the same order in the new collection that it returns.

So even if its desc order the first item in the collection $key may not always be 0.

Use:

```
$pending_apps = $apps->where('status', 'PENDING')->sortByDesc('rank')->values()->all();
```

Which will give you keys starting with 0.